# What is the difference between #include "MyClass.h" and #include ".\myclass.h"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm developing in VS2010 and looking to add code to an already existing project.
This is a Win32/MFC by the way.

And I couldn't help but notice that in class MyClass (in this case MyClass was an extension of the CDialog Class) the following was included at the top of the cpp file:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include ".\myclass.h"
```

I noticed that the second include was typed in without capitalization, but I couldn't quite figure out why?

Comment: Windows filenames are case-insensitve.  The names "MyClass.h" and "myclass.h" are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`MyClass.h`"
 will be searched on INCLUDE_DIR path, which is defined in your project settings.

" `./myclass.h`" will be searched in the same directory than the current file.

Windows files names are not case-sensitive so if your working dir is in your include path, these lines are pointing to the same file.

This redundancy is probably a way for VS to ensure the file will be included at least once...

Edit: thanks Arne Vogel, I was tired and wrote false things.
Your compiler will look for your header files only il the file name is like `#include <file.h>`
But I guess that the redundancy is to be compliant with all file systems.

Comment: Oops ! You're totally right, I was tired... Sorry, I edited my post. Thanks !

Comment: What I mean is there isn't a difference between ".\something.h" and "something.h" mentioned in the documentation. There's only a difference between quotes and angle brackets. The details are implementation-defined and even depend on the OS as you suggested.

Comment: To be honest, the original code seems to be more likely the result of random inconsistency or wishful thinking rather than any more logical reason. :o)

Answer (score 0):

`.\` says to look in the current directory. I'm guessing with the include guards in that header, that wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`#include "MyClass.h"`  is from environment path, while `#include ".\myclass.h"` from current path.

most of the time, "MyClass.h" in the inc directory under your project, but you MyClass.cpp in other path.